# JavaEE app with EJB - glassfish configurations inside project

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb

I have a JavaEE application with EJB, deployed in glassfish. If i add the connection pools, jndi resources, jms resources to the glassfish, then the project is working fine. But is there anyway i can do these things without adding these configurations from the glassfish admin console.

The purpose for this is, when i need to send my project to another person, he/she will also have to add these configs to glassfish. I need to prevent it

Answer (score 1):

Best way to achieve this are probably command line scripts (bat, sh). There you can administrate GlassFish using the **asadmin** command. Here is a list of all asadmin subcommands: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/gcode.html

**Example to add a JNDI resource:**

```
asadmin create-jndi-resource --user admin --passwordfile passwords.txt 
--host pigeon --port 4001 --jndilookupname sample_jndi --restype queue 
--factoryclass sampleClass --description "this is a sample jndi 
resource" sample_jndi_resource
```

*(Example source: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19879-01/820-4332/6nfq988q6/index.html)*

Comment: is there any way to execute those commands when application getting deployed?

Comment: No, you will have to execute them before deploying. But I'd say you can also deploy using a script and therefore combine the two scripts. Here is some documentation on how to deploy by console: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2417/gilfm.html#gijmq